# How much and How many with Money

Tags: nouns

When Money and Rupees are countable nouns why is "Much" used with them instead of "MANY" when asking a question like:

How much money do you have? or How much does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The noun "Rupee" is countable, but the noun "money" is not.

For example: If I have 10 Rupees, and someone asks me:

> "How many Rupees do you have?"

I can say,

> "I have 10 rupees." Because Rupee is a countable noun.

However, if the same person asked me:

> "How much money do you have?"

I can say

> I have 10 Rupees.

But I cannot say,

> "I have 10 moneys." Because money is not a countable noun.

Another way to think os this is that we can speak about countable and uncountable nouns in quantitative terms, e.g.

> I have (no)/(a lttle)/(some)/(lots of) money. (or Rupees)

And we can speak about countable nouns in numeric terms, e.g.

> I have 2 Rupees (or 3 Rupees, or 150 Rupees, etc).

But we cannot speak about uncountable nouns in numeric terms. e.g.

> We cannot say, "I have 2 moneys (or 3 moneys, or 150 moneys, etc).

Comment: Actually, you *can* say *moneys* (or *monies*) in a [specific context](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/money-plural-usage-monies)—although not in the examples you give. But even though it does have a plural form, it's still not countable.

Comment: @Jason Bassford  Agreed. I thought about discussing moneys/monies, but I felt my answer was already long enough given the nature of the question.

Answer (score 1):

*Money* isn't a countable noun. *Rupees* is. So, you say *how much money* but *how many Rupees.*